# Problem upgrading/updating Ubuntu 20.04.4 to kernel 5.15

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bios, sgx

yesterday i updated my ubuntu 20.04.4LTS with newer kernel 5.15.

I think everything works fine, but in boot, i can see some lines with some text, that as i remember didnt appear before.

My dmesg:

```
https://textbin.net/uau0mghguk
```

The error is with SGX that was disabled by BIOS or something like that. Also appear with audit some errors ( dont know if they are important or where before),
If anyone can read and test that everything works ok.

Also would be nice if theres a key to appear the menu where you can choose the boot kernel. Now im entering directly in login window. Thats ok most of the times, but sometimes id need to change the kernel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mine is the same.

I have just updated to 5.15.** version and by now I have problems to run VMPlayer. He ask me to compile the modules, but get error.

When I boot using the old kernel 5.13 from Grub it works great again.